# URL request failing with in Python - cannot find SSL certificate

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl

I have a simple screen scraping routine that gets an HTML page via BeautifulSoup, using a proxy crawling service (Scrapinghub):

```
def make_soup(self,current_url):
    soup = None
    r = requests.get(current_url, proxies=self.proxies, auth=self.proxy_auth,
         verify='static/crawlera-ca.crt')
    if r.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
        if soup:
            return soup
    return False
```

When I run it on an http:// site it works properly.

When I run it on an https:// site it returns this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/danny/Documents/virtualenvs/AskArbyEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 295, in ssl_wrap_socket
    context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs, ca_cert_dir)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Even weirder is that it works when I run it in a unit test accessing the same https:// site.

The only thing that changes between the unit test and the running code is the search terms that I append to the URL that I pass to 'make_soup'. Each resulting URL is well-formed, and I can access both of them in the browser.

This makes me think that it can't be to do with missing SSL certificates. So why does it seem to be complaining that it can't find certificate files?

Answer (score 3):

By specifying `verify='static/crawlera-ca.crt'` in your call to `requests.get`, you are saying that all sites you visit have to have certificates signed by `crawlera-ca.crt`. If your proxy is not rewriting requests/responses and server certificates on fly (**which it shouldn't, but check the update below**), than all your requests to `https` sites will fail.

In addition, if you read the error message carefully, you can see you don't even have that `crawlera-ca.crt` file on disk.

To resolve your issue, just remove the `verify` argument. That way the [`requests` will use the default](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ca-certificates), the [`certifi`](https://certifi.io/en/latest/) bundle (for `requests>=2.4.0`). For non-invasive proxies this is the right solution. Optionally, if you really need to, you can add some of the CA certs you trust to your local `certifi` store, but be very careful which certs you are adding.

**Update**. Looks like Crawlera proxy is a **man-in-the-middle** after all! *Bad Crawlera, bad, bad, bad!*

```
$ curl -vvv -x proxy.crawlera.com:8010 --cacert crawlera-ca.crt https://google.com/
[...snip...]
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
* found 1 certificates in crawlera-ca.crt
* found 697 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*    server certificate verification OK
*    server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*    common name: google.com (matched)
*    server certificate expiration date OK
*    server certificate activation date OK
*    certificate public key: RSA
*    certificate version: #1
*    subject: CN=google.com
*    start date: Sat, 08 Jul 2017 13:33:53 GMT
*    expire date: Tue, 06 Jul 2027 13:33:53 GMT
*    issuer: C=IE,ST=Munster,L=Cork,O=ScrapingHub,OU=Leading Technology and Professional Services,CN=Crawlera CA,EMAIL=support@scrapinghub.com
*    compression: NULL
```

Notice the `CN=google.com` there is issued by `O=ScrapingHub,CN=Crawlera CA`.

This means Crawlera/ScrapingHub is re-encrypting each request you make to your target URL, and **reading all private and sensitive data you exchange with that site**! I understand that's the only way for them to cache origin requests and save some bandwidth across all users scraping the same site, and the only way to inspect the legality of the content, but still. They should put is somewhere in their FAQ, and I'm not sure they do.

Comment: Thanks for this. The file is on disk, but it turns out that the reason it suddenly stopped working was because I moved the python file containing 'make_soup' to a lower-level folder. Changing to 'verify='../static/crawlera-ca.crt')' solved the problem.

Comment: Turns out Crawlera is inspecting all you traffic, and issuing certificates for all sites you connect to. In that case, `crawlera-ca.crt` is necessary. But be aware they can read any private data you exchange with the 3rd party sites.